# tvOS issue with Siri search deeplinking integration

Tags: ios, avplayer, tvos

I have an issue where when user is playing a video , while video is being player, he uses siri to search for a different movie, which will load its corresponding movie details page and then select to play that movie, which deeplinks to your app which is playing a movie, when i play a new selected movie and dismiss avplayer and avplayercontroller, audio from previous video still continues to play. somehow avplayer is not cleared although i clear all subviews from window and initialize its super view controller class again. I am cluless what can i do erase older instance of avplayer. Let me know if anyone has any suggestions or faced similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Are you subclassing `AVPlayerViewController`? If so, that's a bad idea. The API docs specifically say not to do that.
2. Add a `deinit` function. If it's not being called when the old `AVPlayer` is dismissed, you know you have a retention problem. This is often caused by registering for notifications or boundary time observers.
3. If you view controller has a reference to the `AVPlayer` object, you might try overriding the `viewDidDisappear` function to call player.pause() and then setting the player reference first to a new instance of `AVPlayer()` then to `nil`. Not sure why this helps, but sometimes it does.

Definitely implement #2 above. If deinit is not getting called, you most certainly have an issue.